# Hijacking page fault handler

Tags: linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, kernel-module, page-fault, mprotect

I have a process PID that access a memory region that it's not allowed to, the CPU creates a trap into the kernel which calls do_page_fault() which will send SIGSEGV to the user process. The user process has a custom signal handler that has some logic and the faulting instruction is resumed. What I want to do is to move this signal handler logic to kernel space and prevent SIGSEGV from being sent.
For that could I write a kernel module that hijacks the fault handler for this PID or something? or do I have to add my logic to do_page_fault()? Some guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Would be a massive undertaking, but I could see `ebpf` being used for this. A hackier way just for fun and to get something happening faster would be to find exactly where the sigsegv is being sent and don't send the signal if the `current->comm` is equal to the name of your process. Relies on you hard coding the program name and not relying on PID.

Comment: @wxz Out of all things, why use `->comm` to identify the process and not the PID? That's a very NOT unique value that can also be arbitrarily changed during execution. Makes no sense.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Couldn't tell if this is for a legit program or just getting feet wet with kernel hacking. Relax

Comment: in the kernel module, is there a way to hijack this memory access violation trap like using irq_handler() or something?

Answer (score 0):

userfaultfd() could be useful to you. It allows you to handle
page faults in usermode.

Comment: I want to avoid expensive context switches of executing my logic in a signal handler by moving it to the kernel itself, using userfaultfd() defeats that purpose?

Comment: Probably not. The fault would happen anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).